# Webview issue with android 4.0 and 3 .2

Tags: android, android-layout

I created an android Application in 3.2. in that Application i am using using Web View to display an HTML content/website (any website) and its working fine in my  Samsung Tablet (V 3.2)
After upgrade my tablet from 3.2 to 4.0, 
Its displaying content only  in First time in web view,once i exit from apps and i try again second times web-view is not working it displaying white screen repeatedly.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps trouble in activity life cycle.

Are you trying to load webpage from onCreate method? If so, try put it in onStart method.

Comment: It is strange...

Did you check logcat output? Tried it on emulator?